# Orbit around irregularly shaped asteroids

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, orbital-motion, celestial-mechanics, asteroids

I'm curious how would one calculate the shape of the orbit around irregular objects (let's call them asteroids).

How do you tackle this problem? How do you write down basic equations?

In classical mechanics we only mention very simplified problems and the force is always central. But what happens if the asteroid is not a sphere but only half of the sphere or quarter? My understanding is that the force now isn't central force and that you can only approximately calculate gravitational potential.

Comment: I assume you are interested a numerical solution? It seems like quite a difficult problem to solve analytically unless you have a shape in mind. (Or perhaps even then!)

Answer (score 3):

The gravitational potential of an object is

$$\varphi(\mathbf{r})=-G\int\frac{\rho(\mathbf{r}’)d^3\mathbf{r}’}{|\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r}’|}$$

where $\rho$ is its mass density. (This is just summing $-Gdm/r$ for each bit of mass $dm$ in the object.)

You may not be able to evaluate this integral analytically, but you can always evaluate it numerically to whatever precision you require.

You can also use techniques like [multipole expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multipole_expansion) to express it as an infinite series in inverse powers of $r$. You keep as many terms as you need.

Comment: Nice answer! +1 from me.

Comment: Of course, an irregular asteroid probably has a rather irregular density function. So tabulating $\rho(\mathbf{r}’)$ won't be easy. ;) But I guess you can do the inverse problem: orbit things around it to map its gravitational field, and use that to build a density function. We've done that for the Earth: https://www.universetoday.com/116801/the-potsdam-gravity-potato-shows-earths-gravity-variations/amp/ although that also used ground-based gravitational measurements.

Comment: Is seems that I didn't phrase my question right. I know how to calculate (usually numerically) gravitational field. I'm curious what happens when I throw a rock above asteroid's surface. Can a rock orbit an asteroid so that the orbit stays the same and doesn't change with time? With what velocity should I throw a rock so that it circles around an asteroid indefinitely,  so that it doesn't hit its surface but also doesn't escape? Is this even possible? Is this possible if asteroid is half sphere? In this case gravitational field depends not only on radial distance but also polar angle.

Comment: *Can a rock orbit an asteroid so that the orbit stays the same and doesn't change with time?* In general, no. If you know how to numerically calculate gravitational fields, you should be able to numerically calculate orbits and see how they don’t stay the same. Comments are not the place to ask a bunch of additional questions.

Comment: Note that Earth isn't a sphere, and has a nonzero $J_2$, or zonal term (oblateness) in its multipole expansion. This leads to a precision of the orbital plane in polar orbits, thereby allowing sun-synchronous orbits (SSO), as with the A-train.